# How to design a vertical flyout menu similar to this using CSS?

Tags: css, user-interface, menu

[image]

When mouse is hovered on icons in left sidebar, a flyout menu/panel should open. How to do this in css?

**Update :** I created it myself. Need to polish it a little and it will be good to use. Here is the code :

> jsfiddle.net/anujkk/fhb36/103/

Answer (score 2):

I notice you use jQuery to make the menu Full Height. In fact you won't need jQuery by adding these code:

```
#menuwrapper{position:fixed;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;}
#sidemenu{
    height:100%;
}
```

See it here.
http://jsfiddle.net/MenuSo/8drsjhm7/1/

`position: absolute;` is also OK.